# Как реализовать несколько Таймеров с Распознаванием речи?

Tags: java, android

Необходимо реализовать последовательность таймеров которые будут распознавать речь и сравнивать результат распознавания. Проблема в том, что я не могу реализовать несколько `onActivityResult`, где будет происходить сравнение, последовательно, отдельно для каждого отдельного распознавания. Следовательно, все сравнение должно происходить в одном `onActivityResult`.

Вопрос в том, как мне изменить мой `onActivityResult` в соответствии с моими требованиями?

Чтобы в нем происходило сравнение каждого отдельного таймера. Если их будет более 10.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    }, 0);
}
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> results;
            results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            TextView speechText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            String str="";
            for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){
                str+= results.get(i);
            }
            if (str.equals("mercedes")) {
                rightAnswer();
            }else{
                speechText.setText("It's not: " + str);
            }
        }

        private void rightAnswer() {
    Timer timer2 = new Timer();
    timer2.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    }, 0);
}

            }
```

Реализация onActivityResult (2)

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> results;
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            str += results.get(i);
        }
        if (str.equals("mercedes")) {
            speechText.setText(str);
            rightAnswer();
        } else {
            wrongAnswer();
            speechText.setText(str);
        }
    }
            case 2:
                if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    ArrayList<String> results;
                    results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    String str = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                        str += results.get(i);
                    }
                if (str.equals("maserati")) {
                    speechText.setText(str);
                    Log.e("sec", "right");
                } else {
                    speechText.setText(str);
                    Log.e("sec", "wrong");
                }
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заведите идентификатор таймера и посылайте в параметрах его идентификатор, далее в `onActivityResult` ветвитесь по идентификатору таймера.

Только надо учесть в системе может работать только один `Intent`, не совсем понимаю что произойдет если 2 таймера одновременно вызовут один и тот же `Intent` распознавания речи. Здесь надо как то синхронизировать вызов `Intent`, иначе будет каша.

**Update**

Примерно так:

```
Timer timer=new Timer("1"); //задаем идентификатор таймера
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
                int timerId=Integer.parseInt(Thread.currentThread().getName()); //получаем идентификатор таймера
                startActivityForResult(intent, timerId); //засылаем его в Intent
            }
        });
```

Далее после окончания Intent'а

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {  //это и есть идентификатор таймера
              //бла-бла
        }
```

Comment: Поставьте логгер и посмотрите что там происходит